# Magento 2: Not receiving all post params in ajax call

Tags: magento2, admin, ajax, nginx

I have an issue with an ajax call in magento 2. I am unable to receive the whole data from this ajax call in my Post params. As you can see in the images below

[image]

These are the params sent over in ajax

in my controller I have done

```
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    echo '<pre>';print_r($params);exit;
```

I get the following result
[image]

I even tried printing the whole $_POST, but get the same result

The site is setup on nginx. I have tried the following, but whatever values i use i get the same result

```
    client_body_buffer_size 1024K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1024k;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1024k;
```

I need to get all post values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to increase the value of the following param in your php.ini. By default it is 1000, so try to increase it

max_input_vars = 2000

Hopefully that will solve your problem.